# colorize the background of different parts of the graph based on the event

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have a code which create two subplot. I want to colorized the figure based on the values of the black curve.
I want to use three color for the graph.
Every where which the values of the black curve is one, one index befor that to the start should be one color, during that period color 2, and two index after that should be another color. For example:

exactly one From the point which the black curve is one, from index [9:10] color blue, [10-14] red, and [14-16] color green.
[23-24] blue, 24-35 red, [35-37] green.
Can you please help me with that?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
event = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, size = (56, 1)))
event.iloc[10:14, :] = 1
event.iloc[24:36, :] = 1




plt.figure(figsize=(38, 16))


ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()  

ax1.plot(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(300, size = (56,1))), label='1', color='g')

ax1.plot(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3, size = (56,1))), label='2', color='r')


ax1.set_ylabel('m', fontsize=20)

ax1.legend(loc=1, prop={'size': 20})

ax1.set_title('0', fontsize=30)


#ax1.set_xticks([4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40])

#ax1.set_xticklabels(['10 AM', '11 AM', '12', '1 PM', '2 PM', '3 PM', '4 PM', '5 PM', '6 PM', '7PM'])

ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=20)  # Set font size of y-tick labels
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=20) 
ax2.plot(event, color='k')

ax2.set_ylabel('t', color='k', fontsize=20)

ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=20)  # Set font size of y-tick labels


ax3 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
ax4 = ax3.twinx()  # Create a second y-axis

ax3.plot(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(300, size = (56,1))), label='1', color='g')
ax3.plot(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(400, size = (56,1))), label='2', color='r')

ax3.legend(loc=1, prop={'size': 20})

# ax3.set_xticks([4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40])

# ax3.set_xticklabels(['10 AM', '11 AM', '12', '1 PM', '2 PM', '3 PM', '4 PM', '5 PM', '6 PM', '7PM'])

ax4.plot(event, color='k')

ax4.set_ylabel('t', color='k', fontsize=20)

ax4.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=20)


ax3.set_ylabel('m', fontsize=30)

ax3.legend(loc=1, prop={'size': 20})

ax3.set_title('1', fontsize=30)

ax3.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=20) 
ax3.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=20) 

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can modify the plotting part to include the required coloring logic.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Generate random data and set events
event = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, size=(56, 1)))
event.iloc[10:14, :] = 1
event.iloc[24:36, :] = 1

# Generate random data for the first subplot
data1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(300, size=(56, 1)))
data2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3, size=(56, 1)))

# Create a figure with two subplots
fig, (ax1, ax3) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(15, 8), sharex=True)

# Plotting for the first subplot
color_map = {0: 'blue', 1: 'red'}  # Define color mapping based on 'event'

for i in range(len(event)):
    ax1.plot(i, data1.iloc[i, 0], marker='o', color=color_map.get(event.iloc[i, 0], 'blue'))

# Add colored background regions
if i < len(event) - 2 and event.iloc[i, 0] == 1:
    ax1.axvspan(i, i + 2, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.2)

ax1.set_ylabel('m', fontsize=20)
ax1.legend(['1', '2'], loc=1, prop={'size': 20})
ax1.set_title('0', fontsize=30)
ax1.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=15)

# Plotting for the second subplot
color_map = {0: 'blue', 1: 'red'}

for i in range(len(event)):
    ax3.plot(i, data1.iloc[i, 0], marker='o',  color=color_map.get(event.iloc[i, 0], 'blue'))

# Add colored background regions
if i < len(event) - 2 and event.iloc[i, 0] == 1:
    ax3.axvspan(i, i + 2, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.2)

ax3.set_ylabel('m', fontsize=20)
ax3.legend(['1', '2'], loc=1, prop={'size': 20})
ax3.set_title('1', fontsize=30)
ax3.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=15)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I want to have a background with those color. not the line of the graphs.

Comment: you can use ax.axvspan to create colored background regions in the x-axis

Comment: Adjust the parameters of axvspan according to your preference for the background color and transparency.